# Flex memory limit - how to configure

Tags: apache-flex, memory, garbage-collection

Can I control the memory limit (i.e. when GC has to run) in my Flex application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so.  That is probably a parameter of the flash player based at the client, and I assume it is also dependant on the exact resources the client machine has, i.e. more RAM means less frequent gc, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the flash.system.System class. The "totalMemory" property will show you (in bytes) how much memory the current application is using.  Calling System.gc() will run a GC.  You could use a Timer to periodically check totalMemory and then preform gc if it exceeds a threshold.  More info:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/system/System.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure, but I believe the answer is no.  Read [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html).

Comment: The article says nothing about memory limits

Comment: no, but it does speak about how the garbage collector works in the Flash player, which is where your flex application will be running...

Comment: yes, thanks. I'm familiar with Flex's GC, I'm just asking about how to configure it.

Comment: Flex doesn't have its own GC, it belongs to the Flash Player VM.  Flex is just a framework for writing Flash apps.  I think you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: So it there a way of controlling the GC memory limit in Flash?