# Whats the maximum memory that a Flash movie can use in a browser?

Tags: memory-management, flash

I need to store a lot of data coming in from a server into memory, so I have to write my memory-storage algorithms based on how much I can safely use without hanging up or crashing the browser.

Is there any safe size limit like 1MB or 100MB, that contents of global variables should not exceed?

Comment: I'm writing in AS2, BTW, although I can switch up to AS3 if its necessary for better memory management.

Comment: I am using MSIE11 for a flash game, it always crashes after reaching 1.4GB, because that is the memory limit of the browser. The game has a huge memory leak though. I guess this does not matter after 10 years. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how much memory you are using with:

```
trace("MEMORY USAGE: " + (System.totalMemory/1048576) + "MB");
```

Use this to help keep locate memory leaks and to improve your garbage collection code.

In actionScript 2 they say you should both clear and delete dynamically created objects for quickest GC.

```
myArray[0] = "value";

myArray[0] = null; // to Garbage Collect
delete myArray[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no hard and fast limit, but for flash game development targeting mid-to-low end machines, we found that keeping our memory footprint below 500MB reduced random crashing significantly. :-D You'll probably see other scalability limitations (processing power, single threadedness) way before you see memory capacity limitations, unless you are generating a lot data locally, procedurally (e.g. with generated bitmaps.)

I always recommend switching to AS3, but I don't think memory management will be a show-stopper in AS2.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203800/memory-in-swf-flash-player) very similar question and as stated there as well, what you're after might be [here](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/web-development/TCH_WDD/452057-43859701?browseCategory=).

Goodluck.